# Custom Selectbox (jquery script) - Non FF div scroll problem

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, google-chrome, cross-browser

I need a little help...
After read and search for a while I discover a good jQuery plugin to deal with the selectbox custom style problems. I made some small modifications to make it work as I want.  The plugin hide the custom select and append some `div` and `ul` tags.

In **Firefox** 3.6.10 it **works really nice**, but in **Chrome** (6.0.472.63), **Opera** (10.62) when I tried to scroll down the selectbox list (in this case the div with an overflow) **it disappears**.
It looks like a bug, could you check it please? Try to look around line 182:

```
    .blur(function() {...}
```

I tried to make an example so I cleaned a lot of my custom CSS and make it all clear for anyone who wants to analyse it.

[view example HERE](http://www.dev.multisnet.com/code_example/div_scroll_problem.html) and please try it on FF and Chrome/Opera

*PS: I didn't pay much attention to IE... It will be another fight, but i'll keep it for later!*

---

Any help would be appreciated! Thanks for your time!!

Cheers from Portugal

Comment: +1 though being a beginner, you've asked the question by providing required  resources, much appreciated. It really impressed me =)

Comment: tks! if we need help we should provide all the resources..that's my opinion.. I'm familiar w stack for sometime ago, I usually come here to read others questions and answers..but now I'm starting to participate more actively.

Answer (score 2):

Yeah, it does look like a bug.  I'm not sure exactly what the appear and disappear mechanics are for this control, but it looks like when I try to scroll the drop-down area, the `.blur()` style event is firing for the parent control, but no `.focus()` style event is firing for the child control.

You might try delaying the drop-down disappearance by a second for `.blur()` style events, then only hide the drop-down if the `.scrollTop()` of the drop-down hasn't changed (this gives the user a delay between when they grab that scroll bar in order to actually scroll it, and it won't hide if they do so).  That's a massive work-around, but without studying the code a lot more closely it's hard to know if there's a better approach.

Comment: Hi, Tks for your help. I tried to implement it but there are many problems to workaround... E.g. if the user click on the upper arrow and the scroll is already at top the list would disappear..

Comment: Sorry I can't give you a vote up because of my actual reputation... damm!